# why index is not using in order by (foreign key)

Tags: mysql

when i use id (primary key) with order by clause it uses index named PRIMARY but when i use countrycode (foreign key) with order by clause it does't uses index. my output is below.

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE City;
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| City  | CREATE TABLE `City` (
|       | `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
|       | `Name` char(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
|       | `CountryCode` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
|       | `District` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
|       | `Population` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
|       |  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
|       |  KEY `CountryCode` (`CountryCode`),
|       |  CONSTRAINT `city_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CountryCode`) REFERENCES `Country` (`Code`)
|       |  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4080 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM City ORDER BY ID;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | City  | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 4321 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM City ORDER BY COUNTRYCODE;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | City  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4321 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @almasshaikh one row is output of no of rows return in explain query result set(how many queries are processing in your query) not the actual query result set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Very simple mysql query not using index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712319/very-simple-mysql-query-not-using-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `innodb` primary keys are so called "clustered indexes".

It means that the rows physically ordered according the PK values.

Because of that the rows are naturally sorted so it's cheap to read them sorted `ASC` or `DESC`.

Another story is when you `order by` another column.

To use that mysql would have to read both index and data pages, which dramatically increases IO. So mysql decides to sort it in memory instead (because according to its heuristics memory sort is faster than increased IO). If you want to see mysql using that index for sorting you need:

1. Increase total number of rows to, say several dozens of thousands
2. Select only a small subset, like `LIMIT 10`

Then mysql *might* decide to use index.